# Freeing tree that is NOT binary in C

Tags: c, tree, free

I'm trying to free a tree that is not binary. It includes dozens of leaves and paths.
Basicly it's a tree that starts with a root of a chess board position, and includes a lot of other positions.
The structs are the following:

```
typedef char chessPos[2];
typedef struct _treeNodeListCell treeNodeListCell;


typedef struct _treeNode
{
    chessPos position;
    treeNodeListCell* next_possible_positions;
} treeNode;

typedef struct _treeNodeListCell
{
    treeNode* node;
    struct _treeNodeListCell* next;
} treeNodeListCell;

typedef struct _pathTree
{
    treeNode* root;
} pathTree;
```

Basicly I want to free a whole path tree. For example, the path tree looks the following:
[image]

So the root of path tree is the root with "C3" written in it.
(Ignore the parts with the blue "X" on them, it just means that these tree nodes aren't in the tree in my program)

This is the way I was trying to free the tree:

```
void freePathTree(pathTree* ptr)
{
    freeTreeNode(ptr->root);
    free(ptr);
}

void freeTreeNodeListCell(treeNodeListCell* tmp)
{
    if (tmp->next != NULL)
    {
        freeTreeNodeListCell(tmp->next);
    }
    freeTreeNode(tmp->node);
    free(tmp);
}

void freeTreeNode(treeNode* tmp)
{
    if (tmp->next_possible_positions == NULL)
        free(tmp);
    else
    {
        freeTreeNodeListCell(tmp->next_possible_positions);
    }
}
```

But as always, when trying to free memory, I receive dozens of warnings.

How can I free this huge tree without getting any errors? What is wrong with my program?

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code looks essentially right to me, but you're missing `free(tmp)`in `freeTreeNode` when `next_possible_positions` isn't NULL. What are the "dozens of warnings"?

Comment: You should show a [mcve]

Comment: The warning that I'm getting while debugging is: FinalProject.exe has triggered a breakpoint. ---  and --- wntdll.pdb not loaded --- and --- wntdll.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module ntdll.dll

Comment: It is a binary tree if you rotate the picture 45 degrees.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the errors you are getting (formatted as code).

Comment: Logically, you should structure `freeTreeNode` (which has a memory leak on `tmp`) the same as `freeTreeNodeListCell` (which has no memory leak of its own).

Comment: ASIDE: `treeNode` and `treeNodeListCell` could be combined into a single type: `typedef struct _treeNode treeNode;` `struct _treeNode` `{` `chessPos position;` `treeNode *next_possible_position;` `treeNode *node;` `};`.

Comment: Freeing any kind of tree is simple in principle: you walk the graph and free each subobject, deepest first.  Binary trees are not substantially simpler to handle than more highly branched ones.  It is objects whose graphs are not trees at all that are a potential problem.  To deallocate one of these, you must know which links to avoid traversing so that those you do traverse form a spanning tree (which you then walk and deallocate as you do a tree).

Answer (score 0):

The existing `freeTreeNode` function has a memory leak:

```
void freeTreeNode(treeNode* tmp)
{
    if (tmp->next_possible_positions == NULL)
        free(tmp);
    else
    {
        freeTreeNodeListCell(tmp->next_possible_positions);
        // Memory leak here.  `tmp` has not been freed.
    }
}
```

Rather than repeating the call `free(tmp)`, the function can be restructured as follows to be more like `freeTreeNodeListCell`:

```
void freeTreeNode(treeNode* tmp)
{
    if (tmp->next_possible_positions != NULL)
    {
        freeTreeNodeListCell(tmp->next_possible_positions);
    }
    free(tmp);
}
```

---

The `freeTreeNode` and `freeTreeNodeListCell` functions are mutually recursive. `freeTreeNode` could be changed to an iterative function that subsumes `freeTreeNodeListCell` by "flattening" the tree into a list of `treeNode`s and a list of  `treeNodeListCell`s as it goes:

```
void freeTreeNode(treeNode* node)
{
    treeNodeListCell *cell = NULL;
    treeNodeListCell **endCell = NULL;
    while (node || cell)
    {
        if (!cell)
        {
            endCell = &cell;
        }
        if (node)
        {
            *endCell = node->next_possible_positions;
            while (*endCell)
            {
                endCell = &(*endCell)->next;
            }
            free(node);
            node = NULL;
        }
        while (!node && cell)
        {
            treeNodeListCell *tmp = cell;
            node = cell->node;
            cell = cell->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

---

As a more profound change, the data structure could be simplified by merging `treeNodeListCell` into `treeNode` so that there are fewer types to worry about and to reduce the number of memory allocations required to hold the tree:

```
typedef struct _treeNode
{
    chessPos position;
    struct _treeNode *next_possible_positions;
    struct _treeNode *node;
} treeNode;
```

That turns it into a sort of binary tree turned on its side, where `next_possible_positions` points across to the siblings, and `node` points down to the children.

That would make the `freeTreeNode` function simpler. Recursive version:

```
void freeTreeNode(treeNode *node)
{
    if (node)
    {
        freeTreeNode(node->next_possible_positions);
        freeTreeNode(node->node);
        free(node);
    }
}
```

Iterative version:

```
void freeTreeNode(treeNode *node)
{
    treeNode **end = &node;
    treeNode *tmp;
    while (*end)
    {
        end = &(*end)->next_possible_positions;
    }
    while (node)
    {
        *end = node->node;
        while (*end)
        {
            end = &(*end)->next_possible_positions;
        }
        tmp = node;
        node = node->next_possible_positions;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```